# Update remote branch to current changes in git

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase

So I've got the following git tree:

[image]

What I want to do is update the origin/master branch to the feature-7-api-helpers branch, i.e. feature-8-repository would be rebased on origin/master.

Comment: You mean you have some commits in branch "feature-7-api-helpers" that you need to update to master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

1. git checkout master
2. git reset --hard origin/master
3. git pull --rebase origin masters
4. (git branch -D feature-7)
5. (git branch -D feature-6)

Git tree after performing the operations above:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can go to github repo and compare **feature-7-api-helpers** to **master** and merge it yourself. NOTE: Push branch **feature-7-api-helpers** to **origin** remote.